# Magit and GitHub personal access tokens

Tags: magit, github

What is the best way to use Magit with GitHub personal access tokens?

Right now, pushing to GitHub causes Magit to prompt me for a username and password. I have to provide the access token instead of my regular password to authenticate.

Apparently, [cloning with SSH instead of HTTPS](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4zl5hl/magit_with_github_2fa/) is the way to go. However, I've already cloned a large number of repos w/ HTTPS. Can I get them to use the token I've specified in my `.gitconfig` file?

Comment: Inside the `.git` directory is a `config` file which specifies the upstream. You can edit this to change from https to ssh.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magit doesn't deal with authentication directly and leaves that all to Git. The only thing Magit does is that when Git asks the user to provide a password or passphrase, then it forwards that question to the user and later hands the reply to Git.

Git provides many alternative methods for remembering the secret needed to access a remote repository and they all work with Magit. Some of the available options are described [here](https://help.github.com/categories/ssh), [here](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git), and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain).

If you can access remote repositories on the command line without having to provide a secret, but not inside Magit, then that is a configuration issue. For example on Windows your shell and Emacs may not agree on the location of `$HOME`. See [Pushing with Magit from Windows](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows).

Comment: Indeed, this is purely a Git issue. I've solved it using a [Git credential store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store).

Comment: fwiw, I solved this problem (except now that PATs are required, I get authentication failures, so it's a slightly different problem) by deleting the remote through magit, and re-adding it (through magit). After that, sure enough, the git Credential Manager came up and did its magic.