# magit push credentials

Tags: magit

Where does magit get push credentials from?

I have been using magit happily for quite some time.

I installed a new (OSX) machine with the same emacs (spacemacs) config I use on other machines, yet for some reason I cannot push from `magit` on this machine.

On both machines I can `git push` from my user shell just fine (`zsh`). Also, I use `git` and not `https` repositories with github.

So, what are the things I should check?
Where magit gets it's credentials from/what commands does it call/is there an error log somewhere?

Comment: Can you tell us what versions are you using? Also, can you show your configuration files? Finally, have you read this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28361/101)?

Comment: @Nsukami_ thanks your link set me on the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having manual steps in my config to load the ssh agent, which made it work in the console, but was not visible for magit.
Adding any of the git auth methods works (I did it with the ./ssh/config).